# Increase buffer until value is reached?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

Im builder a Buffer based on dealer sales.  The inputs are Dealers points and sales points. I need the buffer to increase distance until 40% of sales volume is reached. Im not sure sure is I should attempt this  **For** and **while** or should I be using get value and create a new field instead?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be more straight forward to:

1. create a list ordered by distance between sales point and closest dealer
2. Iterate that list until you have collected the 40% of sales volume
3. The distance to the last one is the buffer value you are seeking.

btw, it can be done with one sql-query (with or without the final buffering)

Comment: +1. I have to add the same can be achieved without iteration by sorting sales table using two columns, salesperson, distance descending. It is enough to find feature in the sales that sits at the position at FID.Minimum + 0.4*Total_4_this_Salesman.

Comment: This suggestion is somewhat helpful, if I only had a few points to work with.  this is just one step in a much larger model I'm creating. there are 600+ dealers And 300k+ sales points. the sales point distances must correspond to selling dealer and not necessarily the closest dealer.

Comment: Well, 600 points to compare to 300k points is not that much. With a spatial index it is close to nothing :-). And if you combine sales points and dealers by some attribute instead of doing it spatial by distance it is even cheaper.

Comment: I'm still a bit stuck on this problem, What tool do you recommend to create a list between sales point and assigned dealer? Is this something achieved with a custom script? I have tried using near tool but involves insuring  inputs and near have the same selection?..